# SwiftUI function that returns either Text or Button?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a simple function to return either `Text` or `Button`, but I get the following error:

> Function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types

Here's my function:

```
private func cellContent(for cell: Cell) -> some View {
  if (cell.editable) {
    return Button(action: { print("hi") }) { Text(cell.content) } 
  }
  return Text(cell.content)
}
```

How can I fix this or do it different way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is correct variant.

**Note: `ViewBuilder` is disabled when you use explicitly `return`**, so you have to remove `return`(s) when use it otherwise you'll get compiler errors again.

Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

```
@ViewBuilder
private func cellContent(for cell: Cell) -> some View {
  if (cell.editable) {
     Button(action: { print("hi") }) { Text(cell.content) }
  }
  Text(cell.content)
}
```

Comment: (Why parentheses?!)

Comment: @Jessy, no changes in original PO style - who knows, maybe it is project coding standard.

Comment: thanks for understanding, sorry for confusion I am just rushing to build a poc fast haven't had time to set up syntax rules and all

Comment: Thanks again @Asperi, removing the returns is such a valuable hint!

Answer (score 1):

this is the exact `where` of where to use `@ViewBuilder`.
just add an `@ViewBuilder` to the beginning of your function:

```
@ViewBuilder
private func cellContent(for cell: Cell) -> some View {
  if (cell.editable) {
      Button(action: { print("hi") }) { Text(cell.content) } 
  }
      Text(cell.content)
}
```

What is `@ViewBuilder`? you can get detailed info on the internet, but a good, yet short explanation would be that it does exactly what it is doing in this example! it converts `closure`s to `View`s, while removing compile errors.

As said in the comments, you should remove `return`s too, `@ViewBuilder` will turn the whole function's closure to a new single view, and will automatically return that new view, so explicit `return`'s are not needed.

Comment: Thanks!  Just a note in xcode and also @asperi answer, the return must be removed in order to work!

Comment: sure you are right! i didin't check it in xcode, so i missed it. i'll edit.